# i have string like "10.000" i just want 10 as integer how to do it in java?

Tags: java, android

I have a string like "10.000" I just want 10 as integer how to do it in java?

I have done`

```
public static final Comparator<Product> By_PRICE  = new Comparator<Product>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
           //for name
//           return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());

//           return o1.getFinalPrice().compareTo(o2.getFinalPrice());


           return Integer.parseInt(o1.getFinalPrice()) > Integer.parseInt(o1.getFinalPrice()) ? -1
                   : (Integer.parseInt(o1.getFinalPrice()) < Integer.parseInt(o1.getFinalPrice())) ? 1 : 0;




//           if (o1.getFinalPrice().compareTo(o2.getFinalPrice())>0){
//               return 1;
//           }
//           else if (o1.getFinalPrice().compareTo(o2.getFinalPrice())<0){
//               return -1;
//           }
//           else {
//               return 0;
//           }

       }
   };
```

` like this 
i want to use it for my recyclerview if I switch on it will sort my data which am getting from JSON as a string i tried almost everything but cannot find the answer i want to sort it if switch on then ascending and if switch off then descending order

Comment: parse it in double and then cast it to int variable.

Comment: Split the string with a dot as delimiter (`string.split(".")`) and then parse to int (`Integer.parseInt(string)`)

Comment: you can just replace the whole thing with `o1.getFinalPrice().compareTo(o2.getFinalPrice())`

Comment: Please get rid of all the commented lines and provide minimal viable code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[Ljava.lang.String;@3883f0c"
 @MWB

Comment: You're trying to pass MWB's split string as an array to parseInt. Obviously MWB meant that you should pass the first element of the array which is the substring before the dot: `Integer.parse("10.000".split(".)[0])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float) use Math.round()

```
System.out.println(Math.round(Float.valueOf("10.000")))
```

Comment: for that you have to convert string to double first

Comment: it gives me 10.0 not 10 only

Comment: Can you please elaborate where its giving 10.0 in my case its working fine . If you are using double with round that might return an long float should work fine.

Answer (score 6):

You can use BigDecimal

```
String ten = "10.000";
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(ten).intValue());
```

**output**

`10`